# complex analysis, sequence convergence proof

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

So I am taking complex analysis, and was assigned a problem for homework, in no way am I looking for a complete solution for this problem, just guidance on if what I am doing is correct. The problem is to show that (z^n)/(n!) converges to 0, where Z is a complex number.

For my solution to this problem, I started off by proving a lemma (because I didn't see how else to tackle this issue), so through induction I proved n!>2^n for n ≥ 4.

After proving this, this is where I'm unsure on my proof.

Proof: Without loss of generality, suppose 0<Z<1. Now, let ε>0. By the archimedean property we may choose N> (ln(ε))/(ln(z/2)). Then for all n ∈ ℕ≥N we have |(z^n)/(n!) -0|. By the lemma above n!>2^n. So 1/(n!)<1/(2^n). Hence we have |(z^n)/(n!) -0|<|(z/2)^n|<ε. Thus |(z^n)/(n!) -0|<ε as required.

Comment: Why do you not lose generality in assuming that $0 < z < 1$? It seems to me that this makes the problem trivial, because in that case $|z^n|$ decreases to zero, and dividing by $n!$ makes this happen even faster.

Comment: I (also) upvoted.  Nice effort.  **However**, in my opinion, you have taken the **wrong** approach.  For a question like this, your *first try* should be to try to show that $\left|\frac{z^n}{n!}\right|$ goes to 0.  This is the approach taken in Kavi Rama Murthy's answer, which I think nails the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot assume that $0<z<1$.

There exist an integer $N$ such that  $|z| <N$. Note that $|\frac {z^{n}} {n!}| \leq |\frac {z^{n}} {N(N+1)...(n)}|$ for all $n >N$. Let $r=\frac {|z|} N$. Then $0 \leq r <1$ and  $|\frac {z^{n}} {n!}| \leq \frac {|z|^{n}} {N^{n-N+1}} <r^{n} C$ where $C=N^{N-1}$. Can you finish?

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response, I am just struggling to understand a couple things you defined. First, why are we letting r=|z|/N? Is it to clean things up? And from this, how can we see that 0≤r<1. I see how it can be <1, but not the other portion of the inequality. Lastly, why can we move towards the inequality of |z^n|/(N^n-N+1). I just don't see where that comes from. Sorry for all the questions as well, I am just trying really hard to understand this stuff.

Comment: We don't know that $|z|<1$ so using $|z|/N$ where $N>|z|$ gives  us a positive  number less than $1$. $N^{n-N+1}$ comes by observing that the numbers $N, N+1,...,n$ are all $\geq N$. When  you  multiply them you get a number $\geq  N^{n-N+1}$

Answer (score 1):

Not only does the sequence converges to zero, the series, being the exponential series, converges.
Show that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=0$$
Thus, by the ratio test $\displaystyle\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n$ converges. Thus, $a_n\rightarrow 0$.